# Hann Filter in Spatial Domain

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft, windowing

So, Hann filter is:

```
H(k)=(1+cos(2*pi*k/W))/2 , W=2*kmax
```

and based on this, the inverse Fourier of Hann filter is supposed to be:

```
h(x) = 1/2delt(x) + 1/4(delta(x-1)+delta(x+1))
```

where `delta(.)` is the Dirac Delta function. So, if `Hk` and `hx` denotes `H(k)` and `h(x)`, respectively:

```
n = 128;
Hk = hann(n,'symmetric')';
hx = ifft(ifftshift(Hk));
```

I tested `hx` and `Hk` on a sample 1D signal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326374/hamming-filter-in-frequency-and-spatial-domain), and the result seems to be working as I expected. However, `hx` does not look as what I expected which is the sum of 3 delta Dirac functions. What is missing in my code?

[image]

Comment: Apply `fftshift` to your output, it'll look more like what you expect.

Comment: Did you signal in the linked question shift by `N/2` after the convolution? That's your missing `fftshift`!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You were right, I applied fftshift on the hx and output looks to have three delta functions with the amplitudes of 0.25,0.5, and 0.25. However, they are located at x = 1, 0, and 2. Why is there a shift? I was expecting to see them at -1,0,1. Is it because N is even?

Comment: Oh, maybe that's the difference between `ifftshift` and `fftshift`? I always mix those two up! They're identical for odd signal length, but differ by 1 for even signal length.

Comment: Regarding your comment about my linked question, do you mean that I have to do something like this: s3 = fftshift(conv(s1,wx,'same'),n/2);
Based on one of the comments in the linked question, I used cconv and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Or, it's in how you define the 0 frequency? `fftshift` moves the value in the first bin to the middle, so if `hx(1)==0.5`, then wherever that moves to is the zero frequency.

Comment: I don't know `cconv`. But you'd do `conv(s1,fftshift(wx),'same')`. Maybe `cconv` does that?

Comment: @SaraG How are you defining your sample locations?